# How to make such approximation?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion

I have a problem with approximation. The shape of a distorted drumskin is described by the
function $h(x, y)$, which gives the height to which the point $(x, y)$ of the flat undistorted
drumskin is displaced.

Now my question is how to get this approximation:
$\int dxdy\sqrt{(\partial h/\partial y)^2 + (\partial h/\partial y)^2 +1} \approx \int dxdy |\triangledown h|^2/2$ when $h$ is small.
where $\triangledown h= e_x \partial_x+e_y\partial_y$

Thanks!

Comment: Are you still stuck on this problem or did you end up figuring it out?

Answer (score 0):

A taylor approximation $\sqrt{1+x}\approx 1+x/2$ would get you a term like that, but they seem to have neglected the constant term.

Comment: Has my answer helped you here, or do you need further clarification?